# Get the value for every key in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object with key and an array values like this:

```
var obj = {
   key1: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key2: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key3: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key4: ['value1','value2','value3']
};
```

What I want is to fetch every key's arrays.

How can I do this?

I wrote a function using `Object.keys` but it is only fetching the keys of the object:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {

   console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: what do you want to do with these values later? is it okay to just put all of them in an array?

Comment: Try `console.log(obj[key]);`

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm to me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `obj[key]` to access the value of the key `key` in the Object `obj`.

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
   console.log(obj[key]);  // Will be an array
});
```

Better iterator would be [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for (key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

Comment: May I ask why `for .. in` is better than the other one?

Comment: Because in the earlier on You are calculating the keys using `Object.keys(obj)` and then iterating using `forEach` which has it's own limitation as you can not break it. Instead in the later on you are just trying to access whatever comes in. And it looks neat too.

Comment: you are comparing `Object.keys` vs `for ... in` and the breaking of the loop. `Object.keys` have no loop, but the other array methods. `Array.prototype.every` has break and `Array.prototype.some` has break. so why not combine one of these two with the wanted task?

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the items in the object using:

```
for (item in obj) {
  console.log(obj[item]);
}
```

`obj[item]` will give you each array.

Using your existing solution you need to change `key` to `obj[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked..

```
var obj = {
   key1: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key2: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key3: ['value1','value2','value3'],
   key4: ['value1','value2','value3']
};
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
   console.log(obj[key]);
});
```

See Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5t4c4sg8/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with values later, but if you just want to put all of them in an array then simply do

```
var allValues = [];
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {

   allValues.concat(obj[key]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get all key values & then you can push that array into specific array

```
for(var key in obj)
    console.log(obj[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example how to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in combination with  [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

for a short ciruit if the callback returns `true`. It stops the iteration.

```js
var obj = {
    key1: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    key2: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    key3: ['value1', 42, 'value3'],
    key4: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
};

Object.keys(obj).some(function (k) {
    document.write('k: ' + k + '<br>');
    if (~obj[k].indexOf(42)) {
        document.write('Found the answer in ' + k);
        return true;
    }
});
```